# Firestore listening on query snapshot cost

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I have a query that retrieves lasts 10 added documents to the Firestore. Now I run the query and listen on the snapshot for any changes. If a new document is added, is my reading cost 1 document, or 10?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you initially attach the snapshot listener, the server needs to read 10 documents for the query. So you will then be charged for 10 document read.

If then a single document is added and your listener it still attached, the server will only have to read the new document. So in that case you'd be charged for one additional document read.

Comment: That's how I figured. I was just concerned since it's based on orderBy it will return 10 new documents since the order has changed for all documents. Thank you.